# php form converting < sign to &lt;

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a form to post data to mysql.
Whenever i am writing < it gos to database in '&lt ;' form. i want to send it to database as <.
Start of form is as:-

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" name="SEdit"> `
```

and type fields are treated as

```
<?
if($field_type=="input")
{
?>
    <input name="<? echo $spec_id;?>" type="text" class="form-control" value="<? echo $spec_value;?>" />
<?
}
else    
{
?>
    <textarea name="<? echo $spec_id;?>" type="text" class="form-control"><? echo $spec_value;?></textarea>                                 
<?
}
?>
```

What i have to do now?

Comment: None of the code you've posted has anything do to with a database and/or inserting data into it, so we have no idea. Most likely what's happening is that you run it through `htmlentities()`.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is actually find where the error originates from, then I'd replace all of the short opening tags (`<?`) with the standard php tag (`<?php`). Also, if `$spec_value` is to hold this raw DB string (containing `<` and `>` chars, that's very risky business indeed... think about it: if `$spec_value` is `</textarea><textarea name="gotcha">This is messing up your form`

Comment: Sending to database and sending to the browser are two different things and you shouldnt send `<` unescaped to the browser (XSS injection).

Comment: PSR 1 standard advocates for only `<?php` and `<?=`. NOT `<?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `&lt;` and you want to *decode* it into `<` then use:

```
$html = html_entity_decode($text);

echo html_entity_decode('&lt;'); // prints <
```

Comment: Hi please tell me where to place it in code , i am noob in these things..............